# Assigning a cell address to a range in an array

Tags: excel

I have a macro that finds today on a spreadsheet and then I want to search down column for a value, if the value is found I want go to last cell xlleft and hold both values in an array. I have two macros, one to find today and set that as the starting point, I have found another macro to hold the data found. I need help in assigning the value found from today macro into the array macro, below are the macros I have, ie: the address of the date code should be the address the second marco searches from (n), in the code I have(n) = "I2". if possible could this be one macro?

```
Sub FindDate()
Dim R As Range
Dim rng As Range
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:IV1")
  if cell.Value = [Today()] Then
  Set R = cell
End If
Next
  Set rng = Range(R, R.Offset(29, 0)
  MsgBox R.Address
End Sub


Sub FindNames()
Dim strNames() As String
Dim n As Integer
  n = Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
ReDim strNames(n)
Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To n
  f Range("I2").Offset(i, 0).Value = "HA (F)" Or _
  Range("I2").Offset(i, 0).Value = "HA (H)" Then
  strNames(i) = Range("I2").Offset(i, -8).Value & "  " & _
  Range("I2").Offset(i, 0).Value
End If
 Next i
  MsgBox Join(strNames, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CooZk.png)

Comment: I would recommend getting in the habit of indenting your code - makes it much more readable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I refactored the two subs you provided in your question.
Both are now functions that return values.

Furthermore I added a main sub that has two functions:

- configuring the parts of your requirement that might change some time
- calling the functions and returning the values

```vb
Option Explicit

'rename this according to your business model
Public Sub getNamesForHAForToday()

'Configuration part
Dim arrToLookFor(1) As Variant
arrToLookFor(0) = "HA (F)"
arrToLookFor(1) = "HA (H)"

Dim rgLookForDate As Range
Set rgLookForDate = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:IV1")

Dim rgFirstPartOfName As Range 'choose a more useful name here according to your business model
Set rgFirstPartOfName = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")    'adjust to your needs


'part where the work is done
Dim rgColToday As Range
Set rgColToday = getTodaysColumn(rgLookForDate)

If rgColToday is nothing then
    MsgBox "Todays date not found in " & rgLookForDate.address
    exit sub
End If

Dim arrNames As Variant
arrNames = getNamesForHA(rgColToday, arrToLookFor, rgFirstPartOfName)

MsgBox Join(arrNames, vbCrLf)

End Sub


Public Function getTodaysColumn(rgToSearch As Range) As Range

Dim c As Range
For Each c In rgToSearch.Cells
    If cDate(c.value) = Date Then
        'return the intersection of the currentregion-area with the column of todays cell
        Set getTodaysColumn = Intersect(rgToSearch.CurrentRegion, c.EntireColumn)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function


'rename this function so that it fits to your business logic
Private Function getNamesForHA(rgToSearch As Range, arrLookFor As Variant, _
    rgGetFirstPartOfName As Range)

Dim arrNames() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim c As Range
For Each c In rgToSearch.Cells
    If LenB(c.value) > 0 Then   'only check cells with content
        If isInArray(c.value, arrLookFor) Then
            ReDim Preserve arrNames(i)
            arrNames(i) = rgGetFirstPartOfName.Cells(c.Row).value & " " & c.value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

getNamesForHA = arrNames
End Function


Private Function isInArray(value As Variant, arrLookFor As Variant) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(arrLookFor) To UBound(arrLookFor)
    If arrLookFor(i) = value Then
        isInArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the quick response, the coding is a bit beyond my skillset and am struggling to get to grips with it, I tried to work it but the message box comes up blank.

Comment: Did you adjust the ranges to your needs? Another issue might be the date-formatting in row 1. How does the date look like?

Comment: Yes my names are in column A but the date could be in any column, in simple terms find date, loop through date column 29 times to find specified text and find the name in column A and have both name and text in message box. Thanks Ike

Comment: Sorry the dates are formatted 13/Oct/21 and start in B2 :IV2

Comment: I adjusted the code - please try again

Comment: I am getting a error message at this point, "For Each c In rgToSearch.cells" in the Private Function getNamesForHA(rgToSearch As Range, arrLookFor As Variant, _
    rgGetFirstPartOfName As Range)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your sheet to your question. Maybe my understanding of how it looks like is wrong.

Comment: Hey Ike not sure how to add screenshot, I've tried putting the screenshot into the initial post bit it asks to drop into a link? any advice welcome

Comment: Sorted Thankyou for looking again.

Comment: Please try again - I have made some changes to the code

Comment: Hi Ike, I am stepping through the function to find todays date but the c.value is showing as 12/10/2021 I have tried changing the line of code to match this format but it still misses the date.

Comment: hmm - I am on a German windows ... try `IF cDate(c.value) = Date Then`

Comment: Ike That works fantastic thankyou so much, I will now try and learn how it works. Excellent correspondence what an absolute pleasure :)